# jQuery - How to remove event handler only while an animation or function is running?

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, event-handling

I am attempting to create an image gallery. At the bottom I have a strip of thumbnails these thumbnails slide left and right when you click an arrow but if you click the arrow multiple times it ques the function.

I would like to remove the click handler while the function is run, then replace it again.

On a side note, my thumbnail scroller uses margin-left to animate, is it possible to use scrollTo or similar, to move an element a specific amount, horizontally, so if the thumbnails change size, it would still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The easiest way is not to remove the click handler, but simply do nothing in the callback if it's animating already, eg:

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
    if ($('#thumb-strip:animated').size() != 0)
        return;

    /* else animate #thumb-strip */
});
```

If you want to remove the click handler, and add it before, just do this:

```
var animateHandler = function() {
    var params = {}; // animate params
    $('.thumb').unbind('click', animateHandler); // unbind the click handler
    $('#thumb-strip').animate(params, function() {
        $('.thumb').click(animateHandler); // re-bind the click handler when animation is done
    });
};
$('.thumb').click(animateHandler);
```

Needless to say, the first way is simpler.

However what I usually do is not prevent the click event from happening, because the user won't expect that, but I also want to get rid of the queuing of animations. So what you can do is allow the user to click a thumb, and make it instantly animate to the new place with `stop`:

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
    var params = {}; // animate params
    $('#thumb-strip').stop().animate(params);
});
```

This is the simplest and most intuitive solution.

And to answer your second question, you can use `$(this).position()` to get the thumb's relative position to the parent, and then animate based on that.

Comment: Hey thanks for such a detailed answer. I have explored each method and while unbind sort of worked it was quite clunky.

I found a few other examples of stop() and I think that is going to suit best, however I cant seem to make it work, is this right?

http://pastebin.com/ygPYAfsD

Comment: I thought that you'd be scrolling based on the clicked thumb, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The problem with that approach is that if the gallery_nav is in middle of animation, the "current position" is not yet right. What you can do though, is store the position you're scrolling to, and then use that position when the arrow is clicked. Example: http://pastebin.com/fvVXQTJr